# How to get current row textbox value on button click but NOT in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Hi I have the following TextBox:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
  <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_email" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("usr_email") %>' class="custom-table-text"></asp:TextBox>
   </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

If I need to get Eval\db value I can simply do either:

```
<asp:LinkButton.... OnClientClick='<%# "ValidateEmail(\"" + Eval("usr_email") + "\"); return false;" %>'
<asp:LinkButton.... OnClientClick='<%# "ValidateEmail(\"" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "usr_email") + "\"); return false;" %>'
```

**But how to get the value of current textbox (current row)**:

- **inside LinkButton OnClientClick**.
- before postback (client-side\without postback\not in code-behind).

Answer (score 0):

I found it in case anyone finds it useful or has any comment:

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("return ValidateEmail({0}.value)", (((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("txt_email") as TextBox).ClientID) %>'
```